# Проверка формата строки на соответствие регулярному выражению

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить соответствует ли строка следующим форматам телефонного номера:
+79256878975 or 89265489675.

Для этого написал регулярное выражение вида:

```
Regex regexTelephone = new Regex(@"[+]?[0-9]{11}");
```

и с помощью его проверяю

```
if (regexTelephone.IsMatch(telephone))
                {
                    //...
                }
```

Вот эта часть `[+]?`, судя по документации, означает, что в начале строки символ "+" может встречаться 0-1 раза, но в моем случае он пропускает строки с 2-мя "+" - "++79226367891".

Comment: Это в какой документации написано 0-1 раза? На сайте майкрософта написано 0 или несколько.

Comment: _«он пропускает строки с 2-мя "+" - "++79226367891"»_ - потому что успешно матчится часть строки начиная с ее второго символа. Насчет шарповых регулярок хз, а вообще правильная регулярка для полного соответствия должна выглядеть примерно так: `/^\+?\d{11}$/`, квантификатор кол-ва `\d` по вкусу. _//оффтоп: проклятые опечатки!_

Comment: @SoulOFTrue, вот здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference, раздел "Квантификаторы"

Comment: @yar85, а что вот это обозначает ```/^\```?

Comment: `/` - начало литерала рег. выражения (не в шарпе); `^` - начало ввода/строки (в зависимости от флага `m`ultiline; \\ - в данном случае, экранирование последующей лексемы (`+`).

Comment: Хз как тут экранировать \ в monospace-блоке из одного этого символа - время на эксперименты с комментом уже закончилось))

Comment: Я думаю ответ сразу надо давать такой, чтобы +8 тоже не проходило))

Comment: @yar85, в таком варианте у меня что-то и +79225353971 не проходит

Comment: А если тупо в лоб?  Regex regexTelephone = new Regex(@"(^[+]{0,1}[0-9]{11})");

Comment: @SoulOFTrue, я знаю что у меня +8 проходит, но вопрос бал не про этот случай, а про случай когда пропускает "++"

Comment: @SoulOFTrue, _«Я думаю ответ сразу надо давать такой, чтобы +8 тоже не проходило))»_ - если речь о `8` вместо `+7` (`+<кодСтраны>`), то восьмерка это анахронизм из СССР, который надо всячески искоренять, заставляя использовать международный формат номеров.

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir, _«в таком варианте у меня что-то и +79225353971 не проходит»_ - [ЧЯДНТ?](https://regex101.com/r/jLfYfp/1)

Comment: @yar85, да, спасибо, вот в таком варианте проходит ```"^\+?\d{11}$"```

Comment: @SoulOFTrue, спасибо, ваш вариант тоже работает!

Comment: Оформите ответы, я отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях к вопросу были даны верные подсказки. Оформлю ответом.

Самым правильным ответом, на мой взгляд, является решение @yar85:

```
Regex regexTelephone = new Regex(@"^\+?\d{11}$");
```

С другой стороны, моё решение более читаемо:

```
Regex regexTelephone = new Regex(@"^[+]{0,1}[0-9]{11}");
```

Для решения изложенной проблемы подходят оба, их можно использовать с одинаковой эффективностью.